# Why would shiny-bound-input be missing from an actionButton's class

Tags: r, shiny

I have a project that includes a number of actionButtons. Sometimes they appear normally on the screen but they don't work.

When I use Chrome's developer tools to check what's going on, the class on buttons that work includes "shiny-bound-input", while the buttons that don't work do not include that as part of their class.

This class isn't part of the actionButton code:

```
actionButton(inputId="A", label="OK")
# <button id="A" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">OK</button>
```

So Shiny is adding it at some point. To help debug this, it would be helpful to know why a button would appear on the screen normally but not have the "shiny-bound-input" added to its class. I suspect one of the reasons is duplicate inputIds, but that's not my bug today.

----Edit----

A reproducible example is hard when this is a section of code in a multiple-pages of code project. But I found my bug and it was duplicate IDs after all - but the duplicates in this case were two output ids that had nothing to do with the non-working buttons. They were much later in the same chunk of code being rendered.

So at least one solution to this problem is: if your buttons don't work, you might have duplicate input or output ids somewhere in the chunk of code being rendered.

----Edit 2----

And now that I know what the bug is, I can provide an example. Note that the two textOutputs in the code here have the same id. This happens when you copy/paste and forget to update the id. As is, the button in this code doesn't work. But fix the id in that second textOutput, and everything is fine. Also note the lack of any kind of error message.

```
ui <- uiOutput("test_page")

server <-function(input, output, session) {
   output$test_page <- renderUI(tagList(
      actionButton("button", "OK"),
      textOutput("test_output1"),
      textOutput("test_output1")
   ))

   observeEvent(input$button, {
      print("button pressed")
      output$test_output1 = renderText("button pressed")
      output$test_output2 = renderText(input$button)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/actionbutton-demo.html, hope it may help

Comment: I'm not sure when a button wouldn't have that class. Maybe provide us with a minimal reproducible example so we can see when that happens?

Comment: I've added the requested minimal reproducible example. Keep in mind this example comes from a much larger project and that's why it's using the trick of essentially putting the ui inside the server.